# Organización, diseño y encapsulación correcta de las clases de una Actividad

Tags: java, android, android-studio, poo

Como programador junior y de batallas autodidactas, se me escapan bastantes bastantes cosas, y una de ellas son las buenas prácticas. Necesito de vuestra ayuda y sabiduría.

Mi objetivo es transformar una actividad de 5000 lineas, a una que como mucho llegue a 1000. Para hacer esto he pensado en crear el máximo de clases separadas posibles, por tal de separar responsabilidades.

Pero el principal problema que me encuentro es que el comportamiento de algunas views depende del comportamiento de otras. Por ejemplo:

Tengo dos botones (MaterialButton). Los dos abren diálogos con una lista de items. En el primero se selecciona si es territorio nacional o extranjero, y en el caso de que sea extranjero, se visibiliza el segundo botón de divisas.

En este caso ocurre lo siguiente todo en la misma actividad:

1. Se abre diálogo de lista de elementos
2. Según la selección se cambia el texto del botón (nacional/extranjero)
3. Se cambia la visibilidad de los layouts

Creo que este funcionamiento no hace honor a la programación orientada a objetos. Cada clase debería encapsular su responsabilidad. Entonces mi propuesta sería primero creo dos nuevas clases con herencia de MaterialButton: ClaseBtnLocalidad y ClaseBtnDivisa. Y pasa lo siguiente:

1. La ClaseBtnLocalidad abre el diálogo
2. ClaseBtnLocalidad asigna el texto en el botón
3. ClaseBtnDivisa se visibiliza o no, dependiendo de la selección.

Quedaría algo como:

```
btnLocalidad.showLocationDialog()
btnLocalidad.setLocation("extranjero") //asigno el text/tag 
btnDivisa.checkVisibility(btnLocalidad.getState())
```

Pero este tiene sus problemas:

- La respuesta del diálogo de ClaseBtnLocalidad queda aislada, a menos que no implemente un callback. Lo veo demasiado complejo y con demasiado código por algo tan sencillo.
- La ClaseBtnDivisa depende de un parámetro de btnLocalidad y no me convence. Podría crear una clase general llamada Ticket, por ejemplo, que guarda la localidad, y entonces pasaría el objeto ticket:

  ```
  btnDivisa.checkVisibility(ticket)
  ```

También había pensado en otros términos, por ejemplo en herencia:

En la comprobación de formulario hacemos cosas como:

```
if (btnLocation.isForeing() && conceptSelected.isNormal() && divisa.isActive() && divisa.isEuro() && amount.isOk() && App.isLocationActive())
...
```

Y debería realizar herencias para que las cosas dependan de otra manera:

```
1. AppConfiguration (App.isLocationActive())
   2. ConceptConfiguration (conceptSelected.isNormal())
      3. DivisaConfig (divisa.isEuro() && divisa.isActive() && btnLocalidad.isForeing())
          4. AmountConfig (Amount.isOk())
```

El razonamiento sería:

SI-> seguimos bajando en la herencia de clases
NO-> dejamos de comprobar

1. ¿Tenemos la localidad activada en el formulario/app?
2. ¿El concepto necesita una asignación de localidad?
3. ¿Se ha asignado localidad extranjera y por lo tanto la divisa está activa?
4. ¿El valor introducido es correcto?

Debería crear una clase abstracta y crear esta jerarquía? ¿Hay mejores maneras?

También había pensado en crear dos actividades: BaseActivity y TicketActivity

En la BaseActivity abstracta tendríamos como 30 find de Views (lo que es bastante código que me ahorro de mostrar en TicketActivity). Y toda la lógica también quedaría para BaseActivity. En TicketActivity pondría asignaciones de onClickListeners por ejemplo, y métodos generales que sería: ClaseBtnConcept.setTicketUI().

La última cosa que había pensado, es usar la clase Observable. Que con ello mi idea sería realizar varias acciones con un click en una view. No se si esto es posible. Por ejemplo:

Al realizar click a btnConcepto tipo Dieta: se muestre la localidad, no se muestre el layout del  valor, que no se muestre el apartado de introducir foto, que se muestre el tipo de dieta, etc...

¿Buenas prácticas? Me paso a la programación MVVM?

Saludos^^

Comment: Considera que la sobre-especialización mata la reusabilidad. La responsabilidad del botón ya esta establecida: Capturar clicks, por decirlo de alguna manera. Bien podrías especializar el botón a un Mostrador de Diálogo, pero en contraste deberías evaluar el patrón Composite. Por otro lado, casi no hablas del modelo, como si no estuviera bien definido. Por último, cuando hablas de `boton.isForeign()` suena a que estas mezclando -indecorosamente- vista con modelo.

Comment: Por eso digo que está todo en 5000 lineas de código. Todo mezclado. Estudiaré el diseño MVP paso a paso.